# How to associate an extension with a program if the extension is not in the "Default Programs" list in Windows Seven?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows Seven, I'm aware of the "Default Programs" dialog in Control Panel, which lets me associate pre-defined extensions with programs.  However, I need to add an association for a file extension that isn't in the list.  In WinXP, I'm pretty sure I could add entries to the list, but that doesn't appear to be immediately available in Windows Seven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select a file with the desired extension in Explorer and click on it, a dialog box pops up that lets you select a program from a list.  Click that.  Then you can CLick on "Browse..." and select the program you want the file to be opened with.  I have not tried, but you might be able to change it through the Default Programs afterwards.

Comment: That led me to it.  I forgot about the "Always use the selected program ..." checkbox.